# Running Ruby unit tests within maven integration

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, maven

Does anyone have experience with running unit tests written in Ruby from within Maven.

Any inputs, like the library/maven plugin to be used, will be highly appreciated!

We are already using Maven+hudson+Junit. But we are introducing Ruby unit tests, and can't find any equally good combination for it.

Comment: I too would like to know this.

Comment: I can't help you with this question, but are you using RSpec, or Test::Unit, something else, or is that yet to be decided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend having Maven kick off `rake test` using the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) (`exec:exec` goal) and using the [ci_reporter](https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter) gem to produce an XML file of unit test results that Hudson, Bamboo, etc. can read to display test results in the same format that your JUnit tests are in.

If you don't need to run your Ruby tests with `mvn test`, you can also just use the Hudson [rake plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Rake+plugin).

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your response. I will try it out today.

Comment: Okay, I spent some time on this. Looks like your solution will work out. Just that I am not able to generate the XML's with CI Reporter. Could you pls have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038305/cireported-not-generating-xmls-for-ruby-testunits and provide your inputs/suggestions?